# Efficiently iterating over a list of sass variables for retina and non-retina images

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, media-queries

I'm close to figuring this out but I don't know whether this should be lots of media queries or everything in one media query.

Here's a list of countries:

```
$countries: global at au be br ca ch cn cz de dk es fi fr gb hu id il in it jp kr kz my nl no nz ph pl pt rs ru se sg sk tr tw ua us;
```

I will iterate my Scss to output country flags based on this list:

```
@for $i from 1 through length($countries) {
    $country: nth($countries, $i);
    .flag-#{$country} {
        background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_#{$country}.png");
    }
}
```

This gives me one output that I want:

```
.flag-global {
  background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_global.png");
}

.flag-at {
  background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_at.png");
}

.flag-au {
  background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_au.png");
}

[...]
```

I need another list for the retina versions of the images so that the output appends `2x` to each image for the retina version:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1) {

    // Required dimensions shouldn't be included in loop but needs to be in this media query
    .flag {
        background-size: 23px 17px
    }

    .flag-global {
      background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_global2x.png");
    }

    .flag-at {
      background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_at2x.png");
    }

    .flag-au {
      background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_au2x.png");
    }

    [...]
}
```

I'm not sure what's the best way to do this with just one `@for` loop.

Comment: Since Sass only runs when you compile, it's not too important that the code be the most efficient code possible, since it only has to run once.

Comment: I know I can do this with two `@for` loops but I was just thinking there would be an easy way to incorporate the code into just the one. But if this doesn't have an easy way to do this, at least I have a backup solution.

Comment: You could always just have an individual surrounding media query for each individual flag, and do it in one loop, but that would lead to a bigger compiled CSS file and possibly worse performance in the user's browser (not by much, but then, having two @for loops doesn't reduce performance by much either).

Comment: The problem with what you have is what, exactly?

Comment: @cimmanon I wanted to find a way to work the media queries into the original `@for` loop instead of having to write out two of them.

Comment: @micah So put the media query inside the loop?  I don't understand why this is even a question.

Comment: @cimmanon My output needs to be both *with* and *without* the media query. I need retina and non-retina images to display. That's why I can't just loop through with the media queries. My apologies if this isn't made clear.

Answer (score 0):

Like cimmanon mentioned, you can put the media queries inside of the loop and it'll generate the retina classes as well as the normal classes.

```
.flag {
  background-size: 17px 12px; // non-retina

  @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1) {
    & {
      background-size: 23px 17px
    }
  }
}

$countries: global at au be br ca ch cn cz de dk es fi fr gb hu id il in it jp kr kz my nl no nz ph pl pt rs ru se sg sk tr tw ua us;

@for $i from 1 through length($countries) {
    $country: nth($countries, $i);

    .flag-#{$country} {
        background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_#{$country}.png");

        @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio:2) and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio:2/1) {
          & {
            background-image: url("//website.com/images/flags/flag_#{$country}2x.png");
          }
        }
    }
}
```

If you're concerned about all the media queries and would prefer to combine them, you can use the [sass-media_query_combiner](https://github.com/aaronjensen/sass-media_query_combiner) plugin, which would combine all of the media queries together.